# apollo-link-state: How to specify object type parameter on typeDefs less state link?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-client

I am creating my `stateLink` without providing a schema like this:

```
const stateLink = withClientState({
  cache,
  resolvers,
  defaults
})
```

I have a mutation that take an Object as parameter:

```
MY_MUTATION = gql`mutation myMutation($product: Product) {...}`
```

Since there is no `typeDefs` (no `Product` object type), and there is no type checking anyway, how can I specify that the `$product` argument is an object and not a scalar type ?

Comment: I am not sure to unserstand what exactly you are trying to achieve. To who/what do you want to specify the type to? If you are expecting type-checking, you should be using a type-checking tool like flow, typescript or even another language than JS because JS is not typed.

Comment: No you don't get the point. What is here `gql(...)` is not JS, but GraphQL Query Language. I got my answer. With apollo-link-state there is no type checking. So you can put whatever you want there , `Product`, `Int` or whatever, as long as the argument works well with your resolver's code.

Comment: I do get the point :) I use apollo client and server with typescript and use graphql code generator to generate typescript types from my schema and queries. This way I get type checking at compile time

Comment: OK, good to know.